# A sentence using negative construction expresses bad news or the writer’s dissatisfaction or unhappiness. True or false?

Tags: meaning

'A sentence using a negative construction always expresses bad news or the writer’s dissatisfaction or unhappiness.' Is this strictly true?

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine, but I can help you to understand why you received it.  This question is very narrow, and unlikely to help anyone other than yourself.  Also, it sounds like a test question or a homework question, which tends to ruffle some feathers around here.  You might reword you question to ask more broadly about negative construction and how it is used.

Comment: -1 since  “I don't know the question I need help” is not a grammatically valid construction in English.  Please edit the question so that the body of the question is a complete and well-phrased question.  Note, my downvote does not express any concern about the narrowness, if any, of the question, nor about whether it will help anyone else, or whether it is a  test question or homework.  Instead, my downvote expresses my opinion that the question is badly presented and shows little effort.

Comment: The statement is either (1) necessarily true (a negative sentence is defined as one that expresses such material, and vice versa), or (2) total bullshit (since it defines neither "negative construction, bad news," nor "dissatisfaction" -- probably "unhappiness" needs no extra definition -- any construction can be put upon them and contradictions can be generated). Take your pick.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "False" but more accurately it is "Not necessarily."  A [negative construction](http://www.tolearnenglish.com/free/news/0gnegative.php) does not necessarily equate to "bad news, dissatisfaction or unhappiness."

**"That is not a bad thing."**  This sentence uses negative construction to say something positive.

**"I am not satisfied."**  This sentence uses negative construction, and fits within the criteria of the question.

The question as asked is a trick question of sorts.  The writer of the question wants you to think that a "negative construction" means talking about unpleasant things.  That is not the case, and as such the answer is **false.**

Comment: Yes - once the OP's question has been clarified, it is apparent that the problem hinges on the different senses of the word 'negative'. As extreme examples, there is nothing directly bad, depressing, unsatisfactory or ominous about negative numbers, charges or constructions in English.

Comment: Yes: "I don't have tuberculosis" is almost certainly not bad news, dissatisfying or something to be unhappy about. (It could conceivably be any or all of those three, but more likely not.)

Comment: @Andrew Leach: TB or not TB - _that_ is the question.